# ByteBuddy does not intercept public method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to create a deep copy of method arguments using the ByteBuddy agent (this is handy for using ArgumentCaptor of Mockito where the reference to the object is not enough and a deep copy is desired). It works for the private method of the target class but not the public one. The lib I have tested with is version 1.11.19.

Here is the MRE where testPrivate() passes but testPublic() fails. The only difference is the access modifier of the wrapped method in the Print class.

Am I missing something in setting up the agent?

```java
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.*;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.internal.verification.VerificationModeFactory.times;

public class ByteBuddyTest {

    public static class CopyInterceptor {
        @RuntimeType
        public static Object intercept(
            @AllArguments Object[] allArguments,
            @SuperMethod Method superMethod,
            @Origin Method method,
            @SuperCall Callable<?> callable,
            @This Object self
        ) throws Exception {
            if (allArguments.length == 1 && allArguments[0] instanceof Person person) {
                var copiedPerson = new Person(person.getAge());
                allArguments[0] = copiedPerson;
            }
            return superMethod.invoke(self, allArguments);
        }
    }

    void initAgent() {
        ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("Print"))
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module, protectionDomain) ->
                builder
                    .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(CopyInterceptor.class))
            ).installOnByteBuddyAgent();
    }

    @Test
    void testPrivate() {
        initAgent();
        final ArgumentCaptor<Person> personCaptor =
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);

        var print = mock(Print.class);
        var person = new Person(0);

        int count = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            person.setAge(i);
            print.privatePrint(person);
        }
        verify(print, times(count)).privatePrint(personCaptor.capture());

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var p = personCaptor.getAllValues().get(i);
            assertEquals(i, p.getAge());
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testPublic() {
        initAgent();
        final ArgumentCaptor<Person> personCaptor =
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);

        var print = mock(Print.class);
        var person = new Person(0);

        int count = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            person.setAge(i);
            print.publicPrint(person);
        }
        verify(print, times(count)).publicPrint(personCaptor.capture());

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var p = personCaptor.getAllValues().get(i);
            assertEquals(i, p.getAge());
        }
    }

    static class Person {
        private int age;
        public Person (int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    static class Print {
        private void privatePrint(Person p) {
            System.out.println("private - " + p.getAge());
        }

        public void publicPrint(Person p) {
            System.out.println("public - " + p.getAge());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have upgraded byte-buddy to version 1.12.17 and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried registering an `AgentBuilder.Listener` to see if the transformation fails in some way?